# ndk-build can't find arm or mips headers

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

When I try to build with Eclipse under Windows I have the following confusing output (extra paths shortened to '*'):

```
*\android-ndk-r9b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r9b\ndk-build.cmd 
[x86] Compile        : P1 <= CompilationUnitC.c
[x86] Compile++      : P1 <= CompilationUnitCPP.cpp
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libP1.so
[x86] Install        : libP1.so => libs/x86/libP1.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : P1 <= CompilationUnitC.c
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: P1 <= CompilationUnitCPP.cpp
In file included from */P1/Android//jni/CompilationUnitCPP.cpp:9:0:
*/P1/Android//jni/../../../Engine/Audio/AudioSystemAndroid.cpp:15:27: fatal error: SLES/OpenSLES.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This happens to be the first foreign include I make. If I remove this include I get the same problem with stblib.h (!)

I do not have this problem using identical project data under MacOS X

I am especially perplexed how the tools can find the x86 headers and not the arm ones. I have seen this kind of configuration work fine several androids ago... I wonder if there has been some breaking change and there is now some Windows specific configuration that needs to be made.

I've seen a few questions that look like my problem, but on close inspection are totally unrelated. This seems like such an obvious problem that I would not be surprised if there is a question and answer buried under all of the distractions...

Answer (score 0):

So, at some point a breaking change was made so that running ndk-build from within the jni folder does not work.

My 'fix' was to run it from the project root and to adjust my additional include paths to reflect this.

Whilst this works it is deeply disturbing. This should not be a fix... all I can think here is that there is some especially nasty hackery going on in ndk-build which relies on the path implcitily. Even then I struggle to imagine how this would stop the compiler from finding includes in a distant and unrelated path, and especially for just one platform.

I will not accept my own answer until I'm satisfied that there are no genuine replied. I would definitely appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on why this is the case. I much prefer being able to understand a fix than using it like voodoo magic.